# Leaflet: Remove Cursor Panning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a React implementation of a leaflet map with a custom cursor. The cursor's functionality is determined by:

```
L.CursorHandler = L.Handler.extend({

    addHooks: function () {
        this._popup = new L.Popup();
        this._map.on('mouseover', this._open, this);
        this._map.on('mousemove', this._update, this);
        // this._map.on('mouseout', this._close, this);
    },

    removeHooks: function () {
        this._map.off('mouseover', this._open, this);
        this._map.off('mousemove', this._update, this);
        this._map.off('mouseout', this._close, this);
    },
    
    _open: function (e) {
        this._update(e);
        this._popup.openOn(this._map);
    },

    _close: function () {
        this._map.closePopup(this._popup);
    },

    _update: function (e) {
      var latitude = e.latlng.toString().split(",")[0];
      latitude = latitude.replace('LatLng','').replace('(','')
      var longitude = e.latlng.toString().split(",")[1];
      longitude = longitude.replace('LatLng','').replace(')','')
        this._popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
            // .setContent(roundToTwo(parseFloat(latitude)).toString() + String(",") + roundToTwo(parseFloat(longitude)).toString());
            .setContent("lat: " + roundToTwo(parseFloat(latitude)).toString() + String(", lon: ") + roundToTwo(parseFloat(longitude)).toString()
              + " | Relative %: " +  roundToTwo(  parseFloat(  getColor(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longitude)) )  ).toString());
    }
});

L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'cursor', L.CursorHandler);
```

When I move the cursor closer to the edges of the map, however, the map pans automatically (eg: when the cursor hovers near the left side of the map, it begins to pan to the left). I do not want this feature, and only want to be able to move the map via a click-and drag motion, rather it panning automatically when the cursor is moved (without a click).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the map is panning to make sure that your popup does not get cropped by the edge of the screen. One fix for this is to check which edge of the screen you are closes to and adjust the `offset` of the popup accordingly

```
this._popup({
    offset: [0, 0] // change popup position
})
```

```
offset: [0, -30]  // if you're near the top of the screen
offset: [-30, 0]  // if you're near the right of the screen
offset: [30, 0]   // if you're near the left of the screen
```

```
const midX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const midY = window.innerHeight / 2;

const point = latLngToLayerPoint(e.latlng);
if (point.x < midX) {
  // you are closer to left side than right side
}
if (point.y < midY) {
  // you are closer to top than bottom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was actually incredibly simple. In the

`_update: function (e) {}`

part of the code, I simply added a clause:

`this._popup.options.autoPan = false;`

This solves the problem effectively.